# MySQL set ID of primary child with constraint

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have two MySQL tables where the primary relationship between the two is one-to-many. I also need a one-to-one relationship in the parent_table with the ID for the primary record from the child_table. You can kind of think of it as like a dad having lots of kids but having one kid that's his favorite ;P. Is it possible to setup a DB constraint such that a parent can have the ID of a child only if that child is a child of the parent?

```
parent_table (One)
  id: Primary Key
  primary_child_id: {ID from child table}

child_table (Many)
  id: Primary Key
  parent_table: {ID from parent table}
```

Comment: It is possible but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Playing favorites gets you into trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Circular foreign key

> ```
> create table parent
> (
>     id int primary key,
>     primary_child_id int
> );
> ```

> ```
> create table childs
> (
>     id int primary key,
>     parent_id int references parent (id)
> );
> ```

> ```
> alter table parent 
>     add constraint fkPrimaryChild
>     foreign key (primary_child_id)
>     references childs (id)
> ```

First time you insert a new parent record, `primary_child_id` must be null.

> ```
> insert into parent values (1, null);
> ```

> ```
> insert into childs values (1, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1);
> ```

After you have inserted one or more child records, then you can assign `primary_child_id`.

> ```
> update parent set primary_child_id = 1 where id = 1;
> ```

> ```
> delete from childs where id = 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails
> (`fiddle_JKZMCYWHMDENXXNQQOMG`.`parent`, CONSTRAINT `fkPrimaryChild` 
> FOREIGN KEY (`primary_child_id`) REFERENCES `childs` (`id`))
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9196779af2905fc87e639065a2eb4a5e)*